# /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo don't show all mounted disks

Tags: landscape

When I log into my home server I'm created with the output of /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo in the MOTD, however it's missing one of my installed disks and I can't work out why.

```
❯ /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo                                                                   
System load:  0.07               Processes:             133                                  
Usage of /:   50.9% of 11.65GB   Users logged in:       1                                    
Memory usage: 14%                IP address for enp2s0: 192.168.1.10                         
Swap usage:   11%                                                                                                                                                                         
=> /mnt/disk1 is using 98.9% of 2.69TB                                                       
=> /mnt/disk0 is using 94.7% of 1.97TB                                                           
=> /mnt/disk2 is using 94.8% of 2.69TB                                                       
=> /mnt/disk3 is using 94.7% of 586.69GB
```

Disk 4 is missing (df output trimmed for clarity)

```
❯ df -h                                                                                      
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on                                                            
0:1:2:3:4                    16T  8.6T  6.0T  60% /mnt/data                                  
/dev/sdc1                   2.7T  2.7T  1.6G 100% /mnt/disk1                                 
/dev/sdd1                   2.0T  1.9T  3.9G 100% /mnt/disk0                                 
/dev/sde1                   2.7T  2.6T  3.9G 100% /mnt/disk2                                 
/dev/sdf1                   587G  556G  1.6G 100% /mnt/disk3                                   
/dev/sdb1                   7.3T  979G  6.0T  14% /mnt/disk4
```

Any ideas why this is and how I can fix it?

Edit1: Mount Output

```
❯ mount | grep disk                                                                                                                                                                          
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt/disk1 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)                                                                                                                                 
/dev/sdd1 on /mnt/disk0 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)                                                                                                                                 
/dev/sde1 on /mnt/disk2 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)                                                                                                                                 
/dev/sdf1 on /mnt/disk3 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)                                                                                                                                 
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/disk4 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Comment: It could be a few things; it's likely just a filesystem sysinfo doesn't check. Could you provide the output of mount instead of df.

Comment: I've added the output of mount also, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Looking back at it, the "=>" don't just list everything, but rather notes potential issues (disk with >85% use, zombie process, etc). Thus, disk4 has no reason be mentioned.